# Sub-promises in AngularFire - selecting related children by ID?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, promise, angularfire

I have a json collection I've uploaded to my firebase, the sites and tools are related via arrays located in the former that point to keys in the latter

```
  "sites": {
    "s001": {
      "name": "ACT-105",
      "description": "Intro Accounting",
      "type": "course",
      "thumbnail": "debate",
      "toolCount": 4,
      "tools" : ["t001","t002","t003"]
    },
    "s002": {
      "name": "ART-201",
      "description": "Pottery Lab",
      "type": "course",
      "thumbnail": "sculpture",
      "toolCount": 4,
      "tools" : ["t001","t002","t003","t004"]
    },
  "tools": {
    "t001": {
      "name": "main-tool",
      "title": "Home",
      "description": "Main tool",
      "thumbnail": "home.jpeg"
    },
    "t002": {
      "name": "announce-tool",
      "title": "Announcements",
      "description": "System Announcements",
      "thumbnail": "announcements.jpeg"
    },
```

I open a url and promise; then grab the current site and its array of related tools in an array, then open another promise to loop through and get all the related tools.  From the alert, it appears to only grab one tool then quits.

```
    angular.module("foo", ["firebase"]).
   controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", "angularFire", function($scope, angularFire) {
  var dbRef = "https://sampledb.firebaseio.com";
  var siteRef = new Firebase(dbRef + "/sites/s003");
  var promise  =  angularFire(siteRef, $scope, "site", {});
  var sitetools = [];
  promise.then(function() {
      sitetools = $scope.site.tools;
      alert("tools " + sitetools);
  }).then(function () {

      var toolList = [];
      for (var i=0;i<sitetools.length;i++)
      {    
          alert("tool " + sitetools[i]);
          toolList.push(getTool(dbRef,toolId));
       }
       $scope.tools = toolList;
  });
  }]);

  var getTool = function(dbRef,toolId) {
  var toolitem;
  var toolRef = new Firebase(dbRef + "/tools/" + toolId);
  alert(toolRef);
  var promise  =  angularFire(toolRef, $scope, "tool", {});
  promise.then(function() {
      alert("found tool " + toolId);
      toolitem = $scope.tool;
  }); 
  return toolitem;
  };
```

The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/5n9mj/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you should have got the alerts (3 of them) since the iterations went as expected, but the return of the getTool() function is always null: it returns before the promise is resolved and local tooitem variable is not accessible anymore.

Remember that all Firebase calls are async. Also, this code:

```
var promise  =  angularFire(toolRef, $scope, "tool", {});
    promise.then(function() {
    alert("found tool " + toolId);
    toolitem = $scope.tool;
}
```

will trigger race conditions: $scope.tool is bound with the Firebase and there is no guarantee that it would be bound in a specific order and if there will be enough processor time to push it into your array before another promise is resolved. That's why it's better to listen on the value change using Firebase reference than to use angularFire and explicitly bind it to the scope variable.

I think you overcomplicated the code a little bit, you don't have to create new Firebase references every time you are binding your scope variables (unless you're going to use the reference later) with angularFire: angulerFire can accept String url as it's first param.

http://jsfiddle.net/oburakevych/5n9mj/10/

If I were you I would wrap the Tool functionality into a directive with a separate controller, so that each tool will have it's own scope, something like this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="toolId in tools">
    <li><tool tool-id="{{toolId}}"/></li>
</ul>

var promise  =  angularFire(siteRef, $scope, "site", {});
promise.then(function() {
        $scope.broadcast("event:SITE_INITIALIZED");
});

.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", "angularFire", '$timeout', function($scope, angularFire, $timeout) {
    $scope.$on("event:SITE_INITIALIZED", function() {
            angularFire(siteRef + "/item/" + $scope.itemId, $scope, "item", {});)
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the last tip with the scope.broadcast - tho I didn't really understand your example until I read the Angular docs:  http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope

Comment: Also, I see you've included $timeout but it's not used/further defined; the docs for this feature aren't as clear; is your inclusion of $timeout here automatically used by your angularFire call or is it there as a placeholder to be specified later?

Comment: @PatrickHaggood I used timeout in the jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/oburakevych/5n9mj/10/ . angularFire doesn't require the $timeout, but what I noticed - digest is not triggered when new item is added to the tools: $scope.tools.push(snapshot.val()); So I had either to put $scope.$apply() after the push or wrap it in the $timeout which triggers $apply automatically. This could be a question to Firebase guys - it seems to be a bug.

Comment: @PatrickHaggood As for the tip with $scope.$broadcast - I just copy-pasted a controller from my app with all the injections - so it is safe to remove $timeout.